Avoiding recompilation with -buildmode=archive in golang?
Golang noob here.
Lets say I have the two following source files:
calc.go :
package calc
    
func Sum(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}

main.go :
package main
    
import "calc"
import "fmt"
    
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Cashier Application")
    fmt.Printf("Result: %d\n", calc.Sum(5, 10))
}

Lets say I compiled calc.go first with :
$go build -buildmode=archive -o calc.a ./calc.go

This gives me the static lib calc.a.
How do I statically link this with main.go (which imports package calc) without having to recompile calc.go also, when building the former?

Not a solution to your problem here, but this is a very C-like way of thinking. When you build main package, if the calc package needs to be built, the go build system will build it. If it is already built and cached, it will not.

Yes, the go tool already does this for you. If you want to see how to compile and link the individual artifacts, using the -x flag shows all the individual tool commands being executed.
